# azure role : owner, global administrator AAD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, rbac

If i have a user 1, user 2 as a AAD Global administrator , the user 1 create a new domain ,the subscription owner and the user 2 can see the new domain ?

i start from this question to more understand the difference between AAD Global Administrator and the subscription owner

Thanks

Comment: When you say "AAD" do you mean "AADDS" (Azure Active Directory Domain Services) ?

Comment: azure active directory

Comment: When you say domain I believe you are talking about creating a new tenant, if that is the case then by default who is creating the tenant he/she can only have access to it. To access more users, they have to add/invite users to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, they can't.

If you give a user the AAD Global Administrator role in an AAD tenant, he is the global admin in the only one tenant, never relate to other tenants, in your case, the new tenant created by user 1.

For the subscription, it is under a specific AAD tenant. The user need to be created/invited to the tenant, then you can add him as a subscription owner, in your case, if the subscription is under the old tenant, the subscription owner will not be able to see the new tenant. If your subscription is under the new tenant, of course the subscription owner can see the tenant.

Comment: only the creator of domain can manage the new domain , if he didn't add user to this new tenant ?

Comment: Wong : Thanks men !

Comment: And to elevate a Global Admin (in the same tenant) ...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin

Answer (score 0):

No, the 2nd user doesn't have privileges to see the new domain created by 1st user.

**Justification**: 2nd user can see all the resources in the old tenent and make decision in that tenant, but when new tenent is created by 1st user, the 2nd user can't see the newly created domain unless 2nd user is invited to that domain by 1st user who is the owner of the new tenant.